# jQuery code messes up the rest of my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

My entire JavaScript works perfectly, without any errors, but the second I try to use jQuery, I get a plethora of various errors:
[image]

Here is my jQuery code(it uses a jQuery plugin, but I have already used some pure jQuery code before I had used a plugin and had the same results. This code is inside `<script>`):

```
$(function() {
                $("#mailSender").validate({
                    rules: {
                      email: {
                       required: true,
                       email: true
                     }
                   }
                    messages: {
                     email : {
                       required: "This field is required.",
                       email: "Please enter a valid email address."
                      }
                    }
                  });
                });
```

These are the `scrldown()`, `bordcol()` and `bordcolBlack()` functions that are "not defined":

```
function scrldown() {
                var navv = document.getElementById('nav_inn'),
                style = window.getComputedStyle(navv),
                top = style.getPropertyValue('top');
                if (top === "-180px") {
                    TweenMax.to(".nav_in", .4, {top:"20"});
                    TweenMax.to([".trii, .trii_h"], .2, {rotation:"180"});
                }
                else {
                    TweenMax.to(".nav_in", .4, {top:"-180px"});
                    TweenMax.to([".trii, .trii_h"], .2, {rotation:"0"});
                }
            }
```

The corresponding HTML(the `<a>` tag, at first, had the same `href="javascript:scrldown()"` as the rest instead of `onclick`, but both methods work without jQuery):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="scrldown()">
                    <img src="../images/scrl_tri.png" id="tri" height="21px;" class="trii" />
                    <img src="../images/scrl_tri_hov.png" id="tri" height="21px" class="trii_h" />
                </a>
<span class="shop"><a href="javascript:scrldown()">Shop</a></span>
<span class="gallery"><a href="javascript:scrldown()">Gallery</a></span>
```

---

`<div id="wrap-left" onmouseover="bordcol()" onmouseout="bordcolBlack()">`
and(`map-canvas` is a div inside it):

```
function bordcol() {
                document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.borderTop="1px solid #F8CE26";
            }

            function bordcolBlack() {
                document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.borderTop="1px solid #9F9F9F";
            }
```

---

Here are the "`src`" `<script>`s in the `<header>`:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery_validate/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

I have some other plugins, but none are dependent on jQuery and jQuery is also the first one imported.
By the way—if it matters—the plugin is the *jQuery Validation Plugin*.

---

Sorry for so much code, but I truly hope that you guys can help me resolve this issue(unless, of course, I just missed something really stupid. Then just point it out).
It should be noted that my knowledge in jQuery is very limited, and I may be missing something very obvious—to you—and stupid thing, so please, even if you can't see the immediate answer, comment some simple jQuery rule that may not be visible in here but is important/crucial.
Thanks!

Comment: There is missing a 'comma' (`,`)  in your validate() call betweend `rules`  and `messages` ... should be something like this: `validate({request:{...}, messages: {...}})`

Comment: @leo.fcx man, you should've just answered :). It worked! (Well, the plugin didn't do its job, but at least it doesn't mess up anything else. That's a different issue). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the answer is there now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is typo in your code, a comma (`,`) is missing between `rules` and `messages`, it should be:

```
$("#mailSender").validate({
    rules: { ... }, // this comma is missing
    messages: { ... }
});
```